# Redux Form: How to add object for nested properties

Tags: redux-form

I want to have the following model:

```
{
  prop1: string, // required
  prop2: null || {
    prop3: null || string
  }
}
```

I want the user of the form to be able to make the following states (they each have their own meaning):

```
{prop1: "...", prop2: null}            // state 1
{prop1: "...", prop2: {}}              // state 2
{prop1: "...", prop2: {prop3: null}}   // state 3
{prop1: "...", prop2: {prop3: "..."}}  // state 4
```

By default redux-form, will remove empty `{}` objects from the schema:
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1047#issuecomment-221925136

So given this behaviour, state 1 and state 2 are the same, and maybe state 3 is also the same.

I've tried to add a `Field` for prop2, but that didn't work. I would expect a `FieldObject` similar to `FieldArray` with `add` and `delete` properties.

Auto creating parents for nested properties is a cool feature of redux-form, but for the usecase above it does not match...